# How to fix "elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthenticationException: ... missing authentication token for REST request"?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am working on using an ElasticSearch database to store data I am pulling from online. However, when I try to index the data in the database I receive an error.

Here is my code for creating and indexing the data:

```
es = Elasticsearch()

es.index(index='weather', doc_type='data', body=doc)
```

However when I run this program, the second of those lines causes an error, here is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "weatherScraper.py", line 79, in <module>
  main()
File "weatherScraper.py", line 73, in main
  es.index(index='weather', doc_type='data', body=doc)
File "/home/alec/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
  return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/home/alec/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 298, in index
  _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
File "/home/alec/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 312, in perform_request
  status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/alec/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 128, in perform_request
  self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
File "/home/alec/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
  raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthenticationException: TransportError(401, u'security_exception', u'missing authentication token for REST request [/weather/data]')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

''missing authentication token' means you need to authenticate before you can talk to this Elasticsearch instance.  To index documents, the user must have write access. You can include a username and password in a URL like this: http://user:password@hostname:port

For example, in a shell:

```
export ES_ENDPOINT="http://usernameWithWriteAccess:password@localhost:9200"
```

Then in python:

```
es = Elasticsearch(os.environ['ES_ENDPOINT'])
```

Answer (score 8):

The HTTP basic auth can be passed to a `http_auth` parameter when creating the ElasticSearch client:

```
client = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=['localhost:5000'],
    http_auth=('username', 'password'),
)
s = Search(using=client, index='something')
```

This assumes you are using the underlying [`Urllib3HttpConnection`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/transports.html#urllib3httpconnection) transport class which has the `http_auth` parameter.

> ```
> class elasticsearch.connection.Urllib3HttpConnection(host='localhost', 
>                                                      http_auth=None, 
>                                                      ...,
>                                                      **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Default connection class using the urllib3 library and the http
> protocol.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - **http_auth** – optional http auth information as either ‘:’ separated string or a tuple

For SSL and other params to authentication, see the [SSL and Authentication](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/#ssl-and-authentication) section of the docs:

```
from ssl import create_default_context

context = create_default_context(cafile="path/to/cert.pem")
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost', 'otherhost'],
    http_auth=('user', 'secret'),
    scheme="https",
    port=443,
    ssl_context=context,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you do it from Postman tool, for example:

Go to Authorization tab, Basic Auth, write here username and password which you was received by clicking elasticsearch-setup-passwords.bat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For OS Ubuntu:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py
```

```
http_auth=None, -> http_auth=('username', 'password'),
```

Reference:  https://rootkey.tistory.com/113